# Algolia and globalization

Tags: algolia

I am curious if Algolia will work in all countries?  I am concerned about things like China's Firewall which may not allow for it to work.  Is there any documentation on the web about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is unfortunately off-topic for StackOverflow as it is not a programming question, but Algolia just opened its own community forum!
You can send your question there: https://discourse.algolia.com/c/support